# Adjust height of \textsuperscript and \footnote (marks)

Tags: superscripts

I'd like to lower the height of superscripts for certain cases where I'm using very tight leading. Is there a better way than the following? Ideally, the height of the superscript would be no higher than the tops of letters.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\mysuper[1]{\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\textsuperscript{#1}}}
\begin{document}
Food\mysuper{1}
FOOD\mysuper{2}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raise the box containing the item by the difference between the height of a capital letter and the item's height.

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\mysuper[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\fontcharht\font`A-\height}}{\scriptsize #1}%
}

\begin{document}

Food\mysuper{1}

FOOD\mysuper{2}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to use the `sups` feature, I recommend to define a suitable font family.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
\newfontfamily{\lssuperior}{Libertinus Serif}[VerticalPosition = Superior]

\newcommand*\mysuper[1]{%
  \raisebox{\dimeval{\fontcharht\font`A-\height}}{\lssuperior#1}%
}

\begin{document}

Food\mysuper{1}

FOOD\mysuper{2}

\textit{Food\mysuper{3}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, the same with `\scriptsize` instead of `\lssuperior`

[image]

Comment: I can't get this to compile. There's no error message, but I just end up at the `*' prompt.

Comment: @dedded What version of TeX Live are you running?

Comment: lualatex foo.tex
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.17.0 (TeX Live 2023)

Comment: @dedded Those are just informational messages, no error.

Comment: I ran `tlmgr` to update, and am still on the same lualatex version (but 61 packages were updated). All works now.

Comment: I replaced `\scriptsize` with `\textsuperscript` in my real document to get my font's superior glyphs. There's a substantial slow-down in a document with a lot of superscripts, but it works really well.

Comment: Slow down was probably related to this: https://github.com/wspr/fontspec/issues/391

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\lowersuperscript[1]{\textsuperscript{\smash{\raisebox{-0.8ex}{\footnotesize #1}}}}

\begin{document}
Food\lowersuperscript{1} and FOOD\lowersuperscript{2} text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this is great, I didn't know about scalerel. But I don't want to use it this way, because it shrinks the superscripts.

Comment: @dedded Are you sure you have `\end{document}`?

Comment: Oh, I wonder if that was it and not the update. I re-copy and pasted your solution as well as the update, maybe I missed the `\end{document}` the first time (?). Need a facepalm emoji.

Comment: @dedded I have given to you another answer.